# SQL update, string to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an SQL Server database, I have to update some fields, the query is (, is the decimal separator) :

```
UPDATE MyTbable 
SET 
Field1 =   CAST('111,11' AS DEC(18,4)),
Field2 =  CAST('222,22' AS DEC(18,4)),
Field3 =  CAST('333,33' AS DEC(18,4))
WHERE Id = '1'
```

I receive the error :
*Error converting data type varchar to numeric.* I tried with the cast, same problem

Field1,Field2 and Field3 are numeric 38,2

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: try to remove the char ',' in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` instead of `,`

```
UPDATE MyTbable 
SET 
  Field1 =  CAST('111.11' AS DEC(18,4)),
  Field2 =  CAST('222.22' AS DEC(18,4)),
  Field3 =  CAST('333.33' AS DEC(18,4))
WHERE Id = '1'
```

If you want to select these values afterwards as string and with comma then do that:

```
select replace(cast(Field1 as varchar(30)), '.',','),
       replace(cast(Field2 as varchar(30)), '.',','),
       replace(cast(Field2 as varchar(30)), '.',','),
where Id = '1'
```

Comment: OK but when I do a select, the separator must be comma

Answer (score 2):

Take the commas out.

```
UPDATE MyTbable 
SET 
Field1 =  CAST(REPLACE('111,11',',','.') AS DEC(18,4)),
Field2 =  CAST(REPLACE('222,22',',','.') AS DEC(18,4)),
Field3 =  CAST(REPLACE('333,33',',','.') AS DEC(18,4))
WHERE Id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the commas in you query like :

```
UPDATE MyTbable 
SET 
Field1 =   CAST('11111' AS DEC(18,4)),
Field2 =  CAST('22222' AS DEC(18,4)),
Field3 =  CAST('33333' AS DEC(18,4))
WHERE Id = '1'
```

or you can rmove the comma using replace:

```
replace('111,11',',','.')
```